# How to get android phone screen size under uiautomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I want to add a feature on android uiautomator test, that is to identify which is tablet, and which is phone.

you know, we use layout to get screen size like small, normal, large, xlarge, xxlarge

here is my tries:

```
final Configuration config = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration();

final int screenSizeCode = config.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

String screenSize;

    switch (screenSizeCode) {

        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_UNDEFINED:

            screenSize = "screen_size_undefined";
            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
            screenSize = "screen_size_small";
            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
            screenSize = "screen_size_normal";
            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
            screenSize = "screen_size_large";
            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
            screenSize = "xlarge";
            break;
        default:
            screenSize = "screen_size_unknown";
            break;
    }
```

result is:

```
screenSize = "screen_size_undefined"
```

actually my phone screen size is **normal**.

I would like to know how to get screen size from uiautomator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If display size in `dp (device-independent pixel)` would help you figure out the device type, then you can use

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance();
Point p = device.getDisplaySizeDp();
```

Requires: API Level 18

Comment: Why is device.pressEnter()

Comment: I want to get phone type in screensize like Normal, large, xlarge